# The license is due annual maintenance..? Expecting, owing, deserving?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

So I have received an email saying

> The licence is due annual maintenance...

I checked my dictionaries and there is only "due for" or "due in/at/on" or "due to do sth" when something is expected.
I did find one extry that says "due sth" but it speaks about owing, deserving something. Longman etc. do not mention that.

Is the sentence correct like that and if so, what usage of "due" is that? I ask as like I said, dictionaries I tried do not mention "due sth", there is always preposition in between.

Comment: What country is this message from? In AmE you would not use "annual maintenance" in this way (usually we would say something like "licence renewal"). Also make sure it is not spam email, since they are notorious for bad grammar.

Comment: Actually it was an email from my Australian colleague.

Comment: In the USA you wouldn't use the word licence at all.  We'd use license.

Comment: Licence is probably my typo.

Comment: "Licence" is BrE, same as "defence/defense" and others.

Comment: What kind of license is this?  A driver's license? A professional license? A software license?  Each of these kinds of license has different upkeep requirements and terminology.  Based on the term "maintenance", I would guess it is for a software license.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to say:

> The licence **needs** annual maintenance...

Since *needs* is a transitive verb, following with a direct object is fine.

However *is due* is an intransitive usage, so you would not expect a direct object, but a prepositional phrase is fine.

> The licence is due **for annual maintenance**...

Informal usage can omit the preposition though, without changing the meaning, with is likely the case in your email.

Comment: There is the phrase, "give him his due" from which we can derive, "he is due his ten dollars."

Answer (score -1):

"The license is owed annual maintenance" or "The license deserves annual maintenance".

Which doesn't really seem like a correct sentence because having a moral obligation to an abstract concept is strange. But it is the same sense as:

"He is due a promotion." (He deserves a promotion.)